# Followed By Void Is Illegal?

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, compiler-errors, void

I have the following C++ (which doesn't really do anything yet...)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Ranker 
{
    int up, down;
  public:
    void set_ranks(int, int);
    int rank(int, int, int, double);
}

void Ranker::set_ranks(int a, int b)
{
    up = a;
    down = b;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it brings up the following error message in MS V C++

```
1>------ Build started: Project: rankclass, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  rankclass.cpp
1>c:\users\student\desktop\solomon w. c++\rankclass\rankclass\rankclass.cpp(17): error C2628: 'Ranker' followed by 'void' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
1>c:\users\student\desktop\solomon w. c++\rankclass\rankclass\rankclass.cpp(18): error C2556: 'Ranker Ranker::set_ranks(int,int)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'void Ranker::set_ranks(int,int)'
1>          c:\users\student\desktop\solomon w. c++\rankclass\rankclass\rankclass.cpp(13) : see declaration of 'Ranker::set_ranks'
1>c:\users\student\desktop\solomon w. c++\rankclass\rankclass\rankclass.cpp(18): error C2371: 'Ranker::set_ranks' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          c:\users\student\desktop\solomon w. c++\rankclass\rankclass\rankclass.cpp(13) : see declaration of 'Ranker::set_ranks'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Why is this...Ranker isn't followed by void?!?!

Comment: error C2628: 'Ranker' followed by 'void' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)

Comment: ^^^ perhaps around line 12 ;-)

Comment: Why 2 up votes? It seems wrong that *not reading error messages* would be the source of reputation...

Comment: +1 for documenting the question very well.

Answer (score 20):

You are missing a semicolon after the `Ranker` declaration.

It should be:

```
class Ranker 
{
    int up, down;
  public:
    void set_ranks(int, int);
    int rank(int, int, int, double);
};  // <--- Note semicolon
```

Answer (score 4):

Class definitions are followed by a semicolon, add one on line 12.